# Error instaling CocoaPods, error message There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Every single time I install a pod using cocoapds. I get this message:

> Generating Pods project
>   Integrating client project
>   Sending stats
>   Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.

Why CocoaPods is complaining about:

> There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.

I haven't found a way to fix this message.

Any of you know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not an error. Cocoapods is a 'dependency manager'

Here's a text extract that might help:-

> CocoaPods maintains a list of every dependency available through
>   CocoaPods and it keeps a local clone of that list on your machine. You
>   can find it at ~/.cocoapods/repos/master. Before it installs the
>   dependencies, it pulls in any changes from GitHub to make sure the
>   list is up to date.
>
> CocoaPods then inspects the list of dependencies in your project's
>   Podfile. It ensures the dependencies you specified are compatible with
>   your project and its targets. It also checks that none of the listed
>   dependencies conflict with one another. After downloading the
>   dependencies, it installs them in a Pods directory at the root of your
>   Xcode project.

The dependencies are basically what you specify on your podfile under `use_frameworks`. The line tells you that CocoaPods has installed the 1 dependency(i.e: One pod) that you have specified

Therefore, "There is 1 dependency from the pod file and 1 total pods installed" can be thought of as Cocoapods saying "You have specified 1 pod(dependency) in your podfile, we have found the project linked with the dependency, downloaded it to your local pods repository and have successfully installed the one pod out of the downloaded dependency"

Comment: In the directory you mention above it shows this files/directories README.md,Specs, CocoaPods-version.yml,Scripts, netlify.toml. But my initial question still remain. When I ran pod install, the pod was installed. why shows `There is 1 dependency ` ?

Comment: To sum it up again, Cocoapods is a 'dependency manager' and the dependencies are the pods that you specify in your podfile. Therefore, "There is 1 dependency from the pod file and 1 total pods installed" can be thought of as Cocoapods saying "You have specified 1 pod(dependency) in your podfile, we have found it, downloaded it to your local pods repository and have successfully installed the one pod out of the downloaded dependency"